# Proper use of move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php

I used this tag to move my uploaded files to a directory, and it seems that it didn't worked as planed. This is what my code looks like:

```
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = "/var/www/images/";

move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$location.$tmp");
```

Did I supplied the correct arguement? If not, what could be the answer to my problem?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Check permissions of `/var/www/images`. The web server needs to be allowed to create files there

Comment: You mush have write permission.

Comment: There are several ways how to accomplish this, depending on your server and environment. Looks like in your environment, a `chown -R  www-data /var/www/images` would be ok

Comment: Can you pass an article regarding this?

Comment: $tmp contains whole path to temporary file

Answer (score 2):

you must use $_FILES['file']['name'] while giving name to uploading file, try using like this

```
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$location = "/var/www/images/";

move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$location.$name");
```

Comment: I've done that, but the image isn't saving thus it will not appear on my browser. Here is my code for the image: <img src="<?php echo $location.$image; ?>" height="200" width="100">

Comment: Here my code  `<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data" target="resultFrame">`  
`<label for="file">Filename:</label>`  
`<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>`  
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`  
`</form>`  

<iframe name="resultFrame" width="500" height="300"></iframe>

Comment: Or am I missing something here: `$extension = strtolower(substr($image, strpos ($image, '.') +1)); `     or was it wrong after all that's why it is not appearing?

Comment: if you use $_FILES['file']['name']; then extension will be there

Comment: So my codes are correct? That's my main problem. The image isn't appearing and it isn't saving. That's why I can't access the image file on my browser.

Comment: have you given proper permission to "/var/www/images/" folder?

Comment: yeah. It's written as `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/images/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You need to use `name` instead of `tmp_name`

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, "$location.$filename");
```

Comment: @user3335903, You need to use `domain` patha rather than using directory path. i.e you need call as `http://yourdomain/images/imagefilename`

Answer (score 1):

```
$location = "/var/www/images/".$_FILES['file']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location);
```